# Qiblah Direction in Apple watch

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch

I want to show Qiblah direction in Apple Watch. In iPhone i was able to show with Location header with updates with  `"- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading{".`

But with Apple watch there is no magnetometer and unable to use didUpdateHeading.
So please give suggestion how to achieve this?

Comment: Hey,, did you find any solution?